# Software for managing WhatsApp broadcast lists

Tags: mobile, whatsapp

I need a software to manage whatsApp broadcast lists,
in order to

- automatically subscribe (and unsubscribe) new users
- Auto reply to users

do you know any?

Comment: Do you want this on an office PC or on a mobile device? What do you want to trigger the "automatic" subscription? Pull new users from a CSV-file? Let users self-subscribe by opt-in-message? Please give more detail. (I want something similar, so I will watch this space.)